# Convert filter coefficients at one sample rate to different sample rate

Tags: noise, finite-impulse-response, dithering

I was doing some research into dithering in audio, and I was always wondering what Audacity's "Shaped" dither was. Well, turns out it's *noise shaping,* with an FIR filter whose coefficients are:

2.033, -2.165, 1.959, -1.590, 0.6149

The frequency response can be found in [Figure 6B of this paper.](https://github.com/dlh-0492/Function-Noise-Generator/blob/master/Minimally%20Audible%20Noise%20Shaping%20(Lipshitz%201991).pdf)

But this filter is designed for 44.1 kHz.

How would I determine the coefficients that can replicate this frequency response, but at other sample rates, like 48 kHz?

Comment: your link is unreachable for me – Not Found.

Comment: @MarcusMüller S.P. Lipshitz, J. Vanderkooy and R.A. Wannamaker. Minimally audible noise shaping. J. Audio Eng. Soc. 39, 836-852. (1991)

Answer (score 1):

> How would I determine the coefficients that can replicate this frequency response, but at other sample rates, like 48 kHz?

Resample the filter coefficients, just like you'd have to resample a signal. Literally the same methods apply – which also means that your FIR might be longer than just the resampling ratio times the original filter length, because you're (ideally) sinc-interpolating, and hence, getting a potentially infinite impulse response (which you can usually then window with acceptable loss)

Alternatively: find the pole/zero representation, or the continuous-frequency spectrum of your 44.1 kHz filter, and then find the 48 kHz filter that approximates that best.